# Azure Active Directory - Required permissions for Dynamics CRM Online (Microsoft.CRM) missing

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I cannot find Dynamics CRM Online (Microsoft.CRM) under grant permission tab inside required permission after registering my native application through Azure AAD.

Regards,
Shravya

Comment: I quickly checked and I was able to select Dynamics 365 when the Azure AD tenant is an Office 365 tenant. Is yours one?

Answer (score 1):

This should be caused by you didn't have Dynamics 365 (online) subscriptions.

If you want to use Dynamics CRM Online API, you must have Dynamics CRM Online service principal in your Directory. The way of adding Dynamics CRM Online is purchase Office 365 services which contains Dynamics 365 (online).

You can also see [the Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory#prerequisites).

> The user who is registering the application must have a Dynamics 365
>   (online) user account with System Administrator security role and the
>   global administrator role for the Office 365 subscription.
>
> An Azure subscription for application registration. A trial account
>   will also work.

**Solution:**

1. Login to [Office 365 Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home) with A global Admin account which is also an Office 365 account.
2. Click Billing > Purchase services > Buy a Dynamics 365 license or Start a Free trail which contains Dynamics CRM Online.
3. Login to Azure Portal. Then you will see Dynamics CRM Online API in AAD Application Registration.

Comment: Hi,@Shravya . Is this answer helpful?